Is it possible to change the last 1/3 part of the beamer's footline on a specific page?
Such as
% frame 1
|My Name|@title|@date|
% frame 2
|My Name|@title|custom something|
% frame 3: restore frame 1
|My Name|@title|@date|
If it possible, I prefer
% frame 2
|My Name|@title|@date \hspace{xem} custom something|
The MWE is following:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usecolortheme[named=purple]{structure}
\usebeamertemplate{footline}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=black,bg=structure.fg!40!white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!60!white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!90!white}

\title{A title}
\author{The author}
\date{\today}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  Change the last 1/3 part of the footline only on this frame
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \lipsum[3]
\end{frame}
\end{document}


Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.  The solution will depend on your theme.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Okay, the question has been updated with an MWE.

Should the frame number still be printed or just your custom something?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Just custom something is okay.

You could temporarily redefine the page number in head/foot template:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usecolortheme[named=purple]{structure}
\usebeamertemplate{footline}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=black,bg=structure.fg!40!white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!60!white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!90!white}

\title{A title}
\author{The author}
\date{\today}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{frame}


{
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{custom something\hspace*{0.5cm}}
\begin{frame}
  Change the last 1/3 part of the footline only on this frame
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
  \lipsum[3]
\end{frame}
\end{document}



Thank you, the effect is almost achieved. But when I replace custom something with a beamerbutton, the button will move upward some space, and if I add \vskip or \vspace or \vspace* before the button, the layout will mess up (\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{\beamerbutton{something else}}), how can I fix it? (P.S.: I think this may be caused by the default height of the baseline, but I don't know how to fix it)

@Meiu You could use something like \setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{\raisebox{-0.08cm}{\beamerbutton{something else}}}

Perfect! The question is solved~

@Meiu You're welcome!
